# Appending counter to String

Tags: python, c++, string, iterator

I have a function that generates components. The names of these components contain the iterator.

I know how to do it in Python. How can I do the same in C++?

Python:

```
def _default_components(self):
    return {"component{}".format(cnt) : block[cnt]
            for cnt in range(number_of_components)}
```

This results in a dictionary where each component has a unique name:

```
component1 : block1
component2 : block2
component3 : block3
component4 : block4
```

What I'm trying to do now is to pass the `iterator` to the `string` in C++.

In other words, what is the C++ equivalent of this line:

```
"component{}".format(cnt)
```

Comment: That line is not passing an iterator or a generator to a string. Are you asking how to format a string in c++?

Comment: Im asking how to embed the iterator inside a string, such that once I append a variable name it has the iterator which was created from

Comment: That is not what the sample you provided is doing, it is simply appending the value of `cnt` which is in this case an int, to the end of the string `"component"` using the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function. You are not embedding anything into the string. The equivalent in c++ would be something like `std::format("component{}", cnt);` using [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format)

Comment: yes, thats what I want to do, to append the value of the counter to the end of a string. I'll try thanks!

Comment: is this a new function? because I get: fatal error: format no such file or directory after #include<format>

Comment: its part of the standard library you shouldn't need any more import s as long as you have `std` included

Comment: It's a C++20 feature, add the appropriate flag to your compiler: `-std=c++20` and I believe that you do indeed have to also `#include <format>` per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format I don't know what @joshmeranda is getting at. You'll need a fairly recent compiler to take advantage.

Comment: That is *not an iterator*, at least not if you are using conventional python terminology.

Comment: oops, its been a hot sec since I've worked with c++, @sweenish is right about the compiler flag and including format

Answer (score 1):

A similar way of achieving this in C++ would be to utilise `to_string()` function.

Simple demonstration in program is:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

signed main() {
    map<string, string> result;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        result["component" + to_string(i)] = "block" + to_string(i);
    }

    for (auto &[m_comp, m_block] : result) {
        cout << m_comp << " : " << m_block << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output would be:

[image: The output would be]

You can then return the `result` as you want and can modify `i` as per any numeric iterator of your choice.

Moreover, translating your function from python to cpp:

```cpp
map<string, string> _default_components() {
    map<string, string> result;
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < number_of_components; cnt++) {
        result["component" + to_string(cnt)] = block[cnt];
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can read more about to_string [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/).

Answer (score 0):

The new C++20 standard does have a `format()` function but as of this writing it's only implemented in the Microsoft MSVC compiler. Its reference implementation is available as a library from [fmt.dev](https://fmt.dev).

It works a bit differently from Python. The format strings are the same, but it's not a method on the string object. Instead it's used as a stand-alone function, like this:

```
std::string s = std::format("hello {}\n", name);
```

Or, per your example,

```
std::string s = std::format("component{}", cnt);
```